# Converting string to variable name in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

In javascript you can do something like this:

```
var name = 'myVariableName';
myObject[name] = someValue;
```

In Dart, can I get variables from class objects by their name as a string? For example

```
var vector = new Vector3();
vector['x'] = 0.0;
```

Comment: Note: this code doesn't do any kind of casting. You are only setting a property, and property keys are strings.

Comment: checkout [Maps and hashes in dart](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/01/maps-and-hashes-in-dart.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access normal fields of an arbitrary object through a string you need to use mirrors (reflection). You need to be careful, though, since mirrors can increase the code-size of the dart2js output considerably if not done carefully.

If you just need a string-value store, then a Map is what you are looking for.